# Is is possible to grant delete permissions using apex managed sharing?

Tags: sharing, apex-managed-sharing, apex-sharing

I have Custom_Object__c with:

1. Org-Wide Default Settings as: Private
2. Object Permissions in the user Profile:  Create, Read, Edit, Delete.

I have a small development in Apex that is creating some apex managed sharing rules, to give certain users access to records they don't own. 
So far I only needed to give the users either "Read" or "Edit" permissions. So all worked ok.

However, now I need to grant users delete permissions for records they don't own. Without touching profile nor org-wide default settings.
This would mean creating the apex managed sharing rules with accessLevel = 'All'.

I looked into the documentation, it seems to say that it's not possible to do that. (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm)

> All: This access level can only be granted with Force.com managed sharing.

**Does anybody know a workaround to give the user delete permissions for records they don't own using apex managed sharing?**

Comment: One solution i see is to use permission sets.

Answer (score 2):

See this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/183788/39404) I had asked another question on this topic because the [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/21350/39404) by Ralph Callaway didn't work for me (but I really wanted it to)

I am copying the answer from the original question I asked because I
 don't want it to be a link only answer.  I'm putting it here so others
 are not misled to think giving Delete access on the object and an edit
 apex managed share wil let the user delete the record.

The credit for the answer goes to ca_peterson and is reposted here:

> The statement from the docs 
>   http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm
>
> is key here:
>
> > This access level can only be granted with Force.com managed sharing.
>
> in reference to the "full control" sharing setting.
>
> Force.com managed sharing is the term for sharing that is granted by
>   the platform itself - so record owner and manager of record owner if
>   you simplify the statement.
>
> Per [the docs linked
>   there](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm)
>   you need "Full Access" to be allowed to delete.
>
> Pair these two facts together and it turns out that nope - there's no
>   way to grant delete access via apex sharing rules. The only options
>   are to use force.com managed sharing (i.e. change the owner, or be
>   above the owner in the role hierarchy), or grant modify all on the
>   profile/perm set.
>
> The other option would be to make a custom VF page or action that
>   allows deleting the record via `without sharing` apex if the user has
>   edit rights, but that doesn't allow the normal delete DML event, so
>   has some drawbacks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/73723)

Comment: I have added the body of the other question's answer as it pertains to this question

Answer (score 0):

No apex managed sharing deals with row level sharing, i.e. can you view/edit this specific record.  Profile or Permission Sets grant CRUD for an entire object.

So you can programmatically grant a user the delete accounts with a permission set.  This will allow them to delete any accounts they have edit permissions on (which can be granted via apex managed sharing).

In summary, you can't grant a user without the ability to delete an Account the ability to delete a specific Account, but you can grant a user the ability to delete accounts (via permission sets), and the ability to edit the account (and hence delete) with apex managed sharing.

Comment: After doing a little research on permissions sets as I was not familiar with them. I don't see how I can do "grant a user the ability to delete all Accounts they can edit with a permission set". Unless I grant them Modify all data. I don't want to do that as I want the users to only see and edit "some" records (the ones that I'm giving them access via code - apex managed sharing- )

Comment: Sorry @pere, should have phrased that better, they just need the delete account perm.  Updated the answer

Comment: Read/Write on a record does not give delete privileges.

Answer (score -1):

To delete a record:

1. You need "delete" checkbox on object level (through profile or perm set).
2. You need one of the next:
   a) Be record owner.
   b) Have a role above record owner (if object has hierarchy checkbox enabled in
   sharing settings).
   c) Have a "modify all" permission on object or "modify all data" permission.

Comment: Note the question is 10 years old. The question was about Apex Managed Sharing. So how is this an answer to the question?!