# Grant "delete" access level on record using Apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, force.com, apex-sharing, manual-sharing

I am trying to share a record of a custom object using an apex trigger.

When trying to give the access level **"All"**, an exception is thrown :

System.DmlException: Insert failed. 
First exception on row 0; first error: **INVALID_ACCESS_LEVEL**.

**Question :**

- Can we give "delete" access by sharing record using apex ?
- Is there an alternative ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) is quite explicit that All may only be used by Force.com Managed Sharing

> The All access level can only be used by Force.com managed sharing.

You are using Apex Managed Sharing - that is different from Force.com Managed Sharing

The distinctions are [covered here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm)

and summarized below:

Force.com Managed Sharing has three components:

- Record Ownership
- Role Hierarchy
- Sharing Rules (these are the sharing rules you set in the Force.com Setup UI)

User Managed Sharing - the Share button on the record

Apex Managed Sharing (what you are doing) - only Read and Edit may be used

This is all covered in [another answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21345/is-is-possible-to-grant-delete-permissions-using-apex-managed-sharing) here as well